# Horizontal navigation bars that don't use 100% width even when 100% is set

Tags: html, css, width, navbar

I'm trying to make a very basic example website.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwarner112/3zU8Z/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/jwarner112/3zU8Z/embedded/result/)).

I'm trying to start with a navbar. I want it floating and I want it spanning the entire browser width. However, as you will see with the fiddle, the browser is set into the page and does *not* use the entire browser's width.

I've told it to use 100% width, but it cuts off at either side. I've even told it to run at 101%+, but these approaches aren't favorable, because they cause horizontal scrolling.

Every, I repeat, **every** help article I can find on this just says "Make width 100% and you'll be fine!"

This method has *never* worked on me, and I don't understand why.

It's not chrome mis-reading the `width` property, because Firefox has this same issue.

I want this bar to span across the top, much like the bar above us on this StackExchange page.

Can someone help me achieve this? How exactly is this being done?

Note: I know my bar isn't floating yet, I will make it that way.

Comment: Try forcing the body margin to zero: body {margin: 0px}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although everything in your code is correct, you have forgotten to add the following:

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It basically resets all the margins and paddings across all browsers
Check out the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3zU8Z/2/

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset the browser's default stylesheets:

```
html, body {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I understand now. I forgot about the DOM component of pages, and that the `<div>` for the `Navbar` was by default inside the `body`, which already had its own margins.